# ifreq's ifr_names are incorrect?

Tags: c, macos, sockets

The following function determines if a given string is a valid network device name.

---

```
int isValidNDevice(char *name) {

    char data[4096];
    struct ifconf ifc;
    struct ifreq *ifr;
    int sk;
    int nIntfcs;

    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sk < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 0;
    }

    ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(data);
    ifc.ifc_buf = (caddr_t)data;
    if(ioctl(sk, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) < 0)
    {
        perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF)");
        return 0;
    }

    ifr = (struct ifreq*)data;
    nIntfcs = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq);
    for(int i=0; i < nIntfcs; i++)
    {
        safe_printf("%s\n", (&ifr[i])->ifr_name);
        if (!strcmp((&ifr[i])->ifr_name, name)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

When I run this function, I receive the following output.

---

> lo0
>
> stf0
>
> �2�>S
>
> en1j
>
> 0

---

This code worked fine a few months ago. What has changed? Am I doing something incorrectly?

OS: OSX El Capitan

Comment: Ah, so it's Mac OS. Because for Linux your code is correct, but Macs are different, have you seen [this code](https://gist.github.com/OrangeTide/909204) (lines 57-63)? Although maybe it's easier to just use `getifaddrs()` or even `if_nameindex()` (not sure the last one is supported on Mac OS).

Comment: Can you include a minimal but complete program that compiles and runs and exhibits your problem?  You will have a much better chance of getting help.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: nIntfcs = ifc.ifc_len / sizeof(struct ifreq) is not valid on OS X as the returned ifreqs are not all the same size like Linux.  Referring to Apple's [ifconfig](https://opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-306/ifconfig.tproj/ifconfig.c) code might help.

Comment: _Side note:_ After you call `socket` _successfully_, in the remainder of the function `sk` is never closed. So, it is "leaking". All other code paths should do `close(sk)` before function exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array of structures returned by the `SIOCGIFCONF` IOCTL are not of the same size in OSX. They will have a field `ifr->ifr_addr.sa_len`which will be different for each structure

Modified function to take care of this. Hope it helps:

```
int isValidNDevice(char *name) {

    char data[4096];
    struct ifconf ifc;
    struct ifreq *ifr;
    int sk,length;

    sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sk < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 0;
    }

    ifc.ifc_len = sizeof(data);
    ifc.ifc_buf = (caddr_t)data;
    if(ioctl(sk, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifc) < 0)
    {
        perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFCONF)");
        return 0;
    }

    ifr = (struct ifreq*)data;
    for(int i=0;i<ifc.ifc_len;)
    {
        length=IFNAMSIZ + ifr->ifr_addr.sa_len;
        printf("%s\n", ifr->ifr_name);
        if (!strcmp(ifr->ifr_name,name)) {
            printf("Interface Found!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        ifr=(struct ifr*)((char*)ifr+length);
        i+=length;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I would still like to know what changed though. My posted code worked fine a few months ago.